# Problem to play audio instantly for large size audio file

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, audio, html5-audio

I am trying to add audio in my code

```
<audio controls>
  <source src="horse.ogg" type="audio/ogg">
  <source src="horse.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
Your browser does not support the audio element.
</audio>
```

and above code is working fine.. but i am facing problem if audio is quite big. i have to wait for couples of second to listen the audio,

is there is any alternative for the same so we can play audio instantly without any wait?

Comment: Have you tried the `preload="auto"` tag to load the audio on page load?

Comment: No. You need to wait for the file to begin streaming in order for the audio data to be loaded. Server side caching may also help to alleviate this problem, or more bandwidth. It's not going to go away, though.

Answer (score 0):

I found one solution , see if it works :

You can use the following property of audio element to solve your problem!!

Preload hinting:
You can optionally use the preload attribute to give the browser a hint as to whether, and how, it should preload the audio file when the page loads. Preloading the audio file means it can play instantly when the user hits the “play” button, which is a nicer experience for the user.

```
<audio preload="auto"> 
  <source src="WhiteChristmas.mp3">
  <source src="WhiteChristmas.ogg">
</audio>
```

Refer this site:
https://www.elated.com/html5-audio/

Comment: As the OP specified no `preload` attribute, `auto` is used which fetches the whole file instead of just the file length headers as you suggest.

Answer (score 0):

you could try to check the spelling...i to had this problem but when i checked and corrected the spelling of the file,it loaded instantly.The code is:
<audio controls

Your browser does not support the audio element.

Comment: <audio controls
<source src="D:\akul\computer\test.mp3">
<font color=pink>Your browser does not support the audio element.</font>
</audio>