# How can I start playing a very large audio file before it's completely downloaded?

Tags: javascript, html

I have a very large file (1gb) that is on the server and I access it in api
When I run the file in the browser I have to wait until the whole file is downloaded and only then does it start playing,
Is there a way to get the file in parts?
Or how can I make it start playing right away?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57689905/problem-to-play-audio-instantly-for-large-size-audio-file

Comment: The answer there did not help me